# Twig's replacement for Python/Jinja2's url_for function?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am in the process of converting a Python3/Flask back-end (with many jinja2 templates) to a PHP5.6/Twig1 backend. However, while many of the templates transfer nicely to the Twig (since the syntax is very similar), I'm having difficulty figuring out how to replace the `url_for` function from Jinja.

I'm confused as to how this is solved, since it would seem that the url would be dependent on the location of the template (and since I have my templates organized into different directories, the amount of ".."s I use would have to vary based on where the template is (or it could depend on the `.php` file that's rendering the template, and that has the same problems...)

Here's an example template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- begin -->

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | Business Name</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="img/favicon.ico") }}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="css/bootstrap.min.css") }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css") }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="css/font-awesome.min.css") }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="css/base.css") }}">
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        {% include "templates/header.html" %}
    </header>

    <main>
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </main>

    <footer class="container-fluid" style="position:fixed">
        {% include "templates/footer.html" %}
    </footer>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>

<!-- end -->
</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for [assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)

Comment: @DarkBee bundling it with Webpack? The content of the link may have changed.

Comment: Updated link [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#linking-to-css-javascript-and-image-assets)